# How to load all the images from one of my folder into my web page, using Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have a folder named "images" in the same directory as my .js file. I want to load all the images from "images" folder into my html page using Jquery/Javascript.

Since, names of images are not some successive integers, how am I supposed to load these images?

Comment: You can use the **[Directory Slider plugin](http://www.justinwhall.com/directory-jquery-slider/)** which will do that for you. Easy to use and configure. Enjoy

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994212/is-there-a-way-to-return-a-list-of-all-the-image-file-names-from-a-folder-using

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery pull images from directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860743/jquery-pull-images-from-directory)

Answer (score 75):

Works both localhost and on live server without issues, and allows you to extend the delimited list of allowed file-extensions:

```
var folder = "images/";

$.ajax({
    url : folder,
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
            if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
                $("body").append( "<img src='"+ folder + val +"'>" );
            } 
        });
    }
});
```

**NOTICE**

**Apache** server has `Option Indexes` turned on by default - if you use another server like i.e. **Express for Node** you could use this NPM package for the above to work: https://github.com/expressjs/serve-index

If the files you want to get listed are in `/images` than inside your server.js you could add something like:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

// Allow assets directory listings
const serveIndex = require('serve-index'); 
app.use('/images', serveIndex(path.join(__dirname, '/images')));
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.. This is the perfect solution that really worked.. while others failed..

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I can't make it work. I'm using this script in my html file, inside `<script></script>` tags. Any ideas?

Comment: Well it is JQuery man , not Javascript ,USe sumthing like this $(document).ready(function(){    this is basic jquery code writing place

Comment: Didn't work in my case --- gives an error in Chrome: `file:///<my_path>/images/. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

Comment: Can someone explain what "a" is referring to? I have a folder with .pngs and get no results. When i `console.log(data)` I get a very long html document response and the image list appears at the end as `<script>addRow("image1.png","image1.png",false,"","");</script>
<script>addRow("image2.png","image2.png",false,"","");</script>`

Comment: @birgit the `<a>` list is like when you go on localhost and visit a folder with no `index.` file -> you see a list of links to folders and files. What this does is grabbing all those links and retrieving the `src` paths. How you're getting those `<script>` results.. I have no idea :(. A naked Path folder should provide a HTML response with `<a>` elements which the script above is meant to retrieve.

Comment: ok so i stripped down my code to the bare minimum. jquery does work, I added the line console.log(data) into the ajax call and this is the complete output (see the images do appear at the bottom -both tested with and without chrome webserver https://pastebin.mozilla.org/8918253

Comment: This AJAX call throws a 403 Forbidden exception for me.

Comment: @F1Krazy are you trying to make a Cross-domain request? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I don't think I was... I'm trying a different approach now, though, so it doesn't really matter at this point.

Comment: How would you load all files in reverse alphabetical order?

Comment: @BenAlan the files (If I'm not mistaken) should be already ordered by the server - To than insert them in your document - them in reverse order the simplest would be to use `.prepend(` instead of  `.append(` - Could you check and see if it works?

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan .prepend( absolutely worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 52):

Use :

```
var dir = "Src/themes/base/images/";
var fileextension = ".png";
$.ajax({
    //This will retrieve the contents of the folder if the folder is configured as 'browsable'
    url: dir,
    success: function (data) {
        //List all .png file names in the page
        $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () {
            var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http://", "");
            $("body").append("<img src='" + dir + filename + "'>");
        });
    }
});
```

If you have other extensions, you can make it an array and then go through that one by one using `in_array()`.

P.s : The above source code is not tested.

Comment: This worked for me, but I removed .host from var filename. so: `var filename = this.href.replace(window.location, "")`

Comment: Instead of using :contains, use a filter to test for multiple extensions

    `.find("a").filter(function () {return regexp.test($(this).text());}).` 

Define the regexp as 

    `var regexp = new Regexp("\.png|\.jpg|\.gif");`

Comment: some of the file name with special character will not be select. e.g filename= "blk100A#01-01" (will not be select), but filename = "blk100#01-01" (will be select) (without the 'A' before '#')..can help?

Comment: Hi All, I am trying the same example to load 5 static file(5 different html files which are saved in a separate folder) to another file; But files are unable to load in that page. - Any suggestion.

Comment: @Tirtha: Can you post a demo(jsbin/jsfiddle)?

Comment: HI Roy, actually I am trying load all static .html files from my local sytem to my current html page. I tried my best with the helkp of your post -http://jsfiddle.net/bigzer0/4h0nhzra/1/ -any suggestion ?

Comment: Hi, I keep getting a 404 (Not Found) error whenever it tries to load the folder. What could be the problem? I'm loading from a static server

Comment: I managed to get this to work like a charm locally (running IIS Express) and the AJAX call (I logged out `this` returns the full "/assets/images/image.jpg". However when I uploaded it to my Apache server, all the call (`this`) returns is "/image.jpg", causing it to not work on the Apache host. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

This is the way to add more file extentions, in the example given by Roy M J in the top of this page.

```
var fileextension = [".png", ".jpg"];
$(data).find("a:contains(" + (fileextension[0]) + "), a:contains(" + (fileextension[1]) + ")").each(function () { // here comes the rest of the function made by Roy M J
```

In this example I have added more contains.

Comment: some of the file name with special character will not be select.
e.g filename= "blk100A#01-01" (will not be select), but filename = "blk100#01-01" (will be select) (without the 'A' before '#')..can help?

Answer (score 8):

If interested in doing this without jQuery - here's a pure JS variant ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55268506/how-do-i-fetch-all-images-in-a-folder-with-ajax-using-pure-js/)) of the answer currently most upvoted:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "/img", true);
xhr.responseType = 'document';
xhr.onload = () => {
  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    var elements = xhr.response.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (x of elements) {
      if ( x.href.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
          let img = document.createElement("img");
          img.src = x.href;
          document.body.appendChild(img);
      } 
    };
  } 
  else {
    alert('Request failed. Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
  }
}
xhr.send()
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is one way to do it. Involves doing a little PHP as well.

The PHP part:

```
$filenameArray = [];

$handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/images/');
        while($file = readdir($handle)){
            if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
                array_push($filenameArray, "images/$file");
            }
        }

echo json_encode($filenameArray);
```

The jQuery part:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "getImages.php",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                $.each(data, function(i,filename) {
                    $('#imageDiv').prepend('<img src="'+ filename +'"><br>');
                });
            }
        });
```

So basically you do a PHP file to return you the list of image filenames as JSON, grab that JSON using an ajax call, and prepend/append them to the html. You would probably want to filter the files u grab from the folder.

Had some help on the php part from [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122218/get-all-the-images-from-a-folder-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var dir = "test/"; // folder location
  var fileextension = ".jpg"; // image format
  var i = "1";

  $(function imageloop(){
    $("<img />").attr('src', dir + i + fileextension ).appendTo(".testing");
    if (i==13){
      alert('loaded');
    }
    else{
      i++;
      imageloop();
    };
  });   
});
```

For this script, I have named my image files in a folder as `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, `3.jpg`, ... to `13.jpg`.

You can change directory and file names as you wish.

Comment: The OP's question requires "names of images are not some successive integers"

Answer (score 1):

If, as in my case, you would like to load the images from a local folder on your own machine, then there is a simple way to do it with a very short Windows batch file. This uses the ability to send the output of any command to a file using > (to overwrite a file) and >> (to append to a file).

Potentially, you could output a list of filenames to a plain text file like this:

```
dir /B > filenames.txt
```

However, reading in a text file requires more faffing around, so I output a javascript file instead, which can then be loaded in your to create a global variable with all the filenames in it.

```
echo var g_FOLDER_CONTENTS = mlString(function() { /*! > folder_contents.js
dir /B images >> folder_contents.js
echo */}); >> folder_contents.js
```

The reason for the weird function with comment inside notation is to get around the limitation on multi-line strings in Javascript. The output of the dir command cannot be formatted to write a correct string, so I found a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript).

```
function mlString(f) {
    return f.toString().
        replace(/^[^\/]+\/\*!?/, '').
        replace(/\*\/[^\/]+$/, '');
}
```

Add this in your main code before the generated javascript file is run, and then you will have a global variable called g_FOLDER_CONTENTS, which is a string containing the output from the dir command. This can then be tokenized and you'll have a list of filenames, with which you can do what you like.

```
var filenames = g_FOLDER_CONTENTS.match(/\S+/g);
```

Here's an example of it all put together: [image_loader.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2HO-DwxAPCnZXppWnprWU1VcjQ/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-dZblDX27MTs6d4f3bb_HWQ)

In the example, **run.bat** generates the Javascript file and opens index.html, so you needn't open index.html yourself.

**NOTE**: .bat is an executable type in Windows, so open them in a text editor before running if you are downloading from some random internet link like this one.

If you are running Linux or OSX, you can probably do something similar to the batch file and produce a correctly formatted javascript string without any of the mlString faff.

Comment: Voted you up for the note :D

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that works for me, what I want is to list the images directly on my page so that you just have to put the directory where you can find the images for example -> dir = "images /"
    I do a substring `var pathName = filename.substring (filename.lastIndexOf ('/') + 1);`
    with which I make sure to just bring the name of the files listed and at the end I link my URL to publish it in the body

```
$ ("body"). append ($ ("<img src =" + dir + pathName + "> </ img>"));
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>


        var dir = "imagenes/";
        var fileextension = ".jpg";
        $.ajax({
            //This will retrieve the contents of the folder if the folder is configured as 'browsable'
            url: dir,
            success: function (data) {
                //Lsit all png file names in the page
                $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () {
                    var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.pathname, "").replace("http://", "");
            var pathName = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);               
                    $("body").append($("<img src=" + dir + pathName + "></img>"));
            console.log(dir+pathName);
                });
            }
        });



        </script>

  </head>
  <body>
<img src="1_1.jpg">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer of Roko C. Buljan, I have created this method which gets images from a folder and **its subfolders** . This might need some error handling but works fine for a simple folder structure.

```
var findImages = function(){
    var parentDir = "./Resource/materials/";

    var fileCrowler = function(data){
        var titlestr = $(data).filter('title').text();
        // "Directory listing for /Resource/materials/xxx"
        var thisDirectory = titlestr.slice(titlestr.indexOf('/'), titlestr.length)

        //List all image file names in the page
        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, filename) {
            if( filename.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
                var fileNameWOExtension = filename.slice(0, filename.lastIndexOf('.'))
                var img_html = "<img src='{0}' id='{1}' alt='{2}' width='75' height='75' hspace='2' vspace='2' onclick='onImageSelection(this);'>".format(thisDirectory + filename, fileNameWOExtension, fileNameWOExtension);
                $("#image_pane").append(img_html);
            }
            else{ 
                $.ajax({
                    url: thisDirectory + filename,
                    success: fileCrowler
                });
            }
        });}

        $.ajax({
        url: parentDir,
        success: fileCrowler
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this automatically. Your JS can't see the files in the same directory as it.

Easiest is probably to give a list of those image names to your JavaScript.

Otherwise, you might be able to fetch a directory listing from the web server using JS and parse it to get the list of images.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can use Ajax to call a server-side script. The server-side script will find all the files in the folder and return them to your html file where you will need to process the returned information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [fs.readdir](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/fs.html#fs.readdir) or [fs.readdirSync](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/fs.html#fs.readdirSync) methods to get the file names in the directory.

The difference between the two methods, is that the first one is asynchronous, so you have to provide a callback function that will be executed when the read process ends.

The second is synchronous, it will returns the file name array, but it will stop any further execution of your code until the read process ends.

After that you simply have to iterate through the names and using append function, add them to their appropriate locations. To check out how it works see [HTML DOM and JS reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function mlString(f) {
    return f.toString().
        replace(/^[^\/]+\/\*!?/, '');
        replace(/\*\/[^\/]+$/, '');
}

function run_onload() {
    console.log("Sample text for console");
    var filenames = g_FOLDER_CONTENTS.match(/\S+/g);
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (var i = 0; i < filenames.length; ++i) {
        var extension = filenames[i].substring(filenames[i].length-3);
        if (extension == "png" || extension == "jpg") {

var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
iDiv.id = 'images';
iDiv.className = 'item';
document.getElementById("image_div").appendChild(iDiv);
iDiv.appendChild(fragment);

            var image = document.createElement("img");
            image.className = "fancybox";
            image.src = "images/" + filenames[i];
            fragment.appendChild(image);
        }
    }
     document.getElementById("images").appendChild(fragment);

}

</script>
```

then create a js file with the following:

```
var g_FOLDER_CONTENTS = mlString(function() { /*! 
1.png
2.png
3.png 
*/});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Chrome, searching for the images files in links (as proposed previously) didn't work as it is generating something like:

```
(...) i18nTemplate.process(document, loadTimeData);
</script>
<script>start("current directory...")</script>
<script>addRow("..","..",1,"170 B","10/2/15, 8:32:45 PM");</script>
<script>addRow("fotos-interessantes-11.jpg","fotos-interessantes-> 11.jpg",false,"","");</script>
```

Maybe the most reliable way is to do something like this:

```js
var folder = "img/";

$.ajax({
    url : folder,
    success: function (data) {
        var patt1 = /"([^"]*\.(jpe?g|png|gif))"/gi;     // extract "*.jpeg" or "*.jpg" or "*.png" or "*.gif"
        var result = data.match(patt1);
        result = result.map(function(el) { return el.replace(/"/g, ""); });     // remove double quotes (") surrounding filename+extension // TODO: do this at regex!

        var uniqueNames = [];                               // this array will help to remove duplicate images
        $.each(result, function(i, el){
            var el_url_encoded = encodeURIComponent(el);    // avoid images with same name but converted to URL encoded
            console.log("under analysis: " + el);
            if($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1  &&  $.inArray(el_url_encoded, uniqueNames) === -1){
                console.log("adding " + el_url_encoded);
                uniqueNames.push(el_url_encoded);
                $("#slider").append( "<img src='" + el_url_encoded +"' alt=''>" );      // finaly add to HTML
            } else{   console.log(el_url_encoded + " already in!"); }
        });
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, err) {
       alert('Error: here we go...');
       alert(textStatus);
       alert(err);
       alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\n xhrStatus: "+xhr.status);
       alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone using Webpack that searched "javascript get images from folder" on Google...

For cases like: `background-image: url("data:image/png;foo...");`

`npm install url-loader --save-dev`

```js
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|webp|gif)$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,  // Smaller than 10 kb
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then it's pretty straightforward.

```
const imageContext = require.context('/path/to/images/', false, /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|webp|gif)$/);
const imageArray = imageContext.keys().map(imageContext);
```

If you console.log `imageArray` you're going to see something like this:

```
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]
0: Closure (./assets/img/badges/badge-1.webp)
__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__:"data:image/webp;base64,UklGRjQJAABXRUJQVlA4WAoAAAA8AAAAGAAAFwAASUNDULgCA
```

And you can access the base64 encoded image data using the `default` property on the module.

```
const imageContext = require.context('/assets/img/badges/', false, /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|webp|gif)$/);
const imageArray = imageContext.keys().map(imageContext);
const base64Images = imageArray.map(module => module.default);
```

So now you end up with this:

[image]