# How do i get images file name from a given folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got a task to display all images inside a folder using jquery.

For that i used the code

```
var imageFolder = '../../Images/Avatar/';
var imgsrc = imageFolder +'';
```

I need to get the images file name inside that folder avatar. How can I get the file name. There are lot of image files in that avatar folder also has some txt files.I only need jpg,png,gif images only.

Comment: So I am guessing: The directory you want to do a listing of files with `jpeg`, `png` and `gif` extensions for resides on some **server** which exposes them via web server. You have to get references to the files for some reason on the **client side**. Do you need the path or the URI of the files? Is there some sort of directory listing readily available from your web server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this way

HTML CODE:

```
<div id='fileNames'> </div>
```

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
var fileExt = {},
    fileExt[0]=".png",
    fileExt[1]=".jpg",
    fileExt[2]=".gif";
$.ajax({
    //This will retrieve the contents of the folder if the folder is configured as 'browsable'
    url: '../../Images/Avatar/',
    success: function (data) {
       $("#fileNames").html('<ul>');
       //List all png or jpg or gif file names in the page
       $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileExt[0] + "),a:contains(" + fileExt[1] + "),a:contains(" + fileExt[2] + ")").each(function () {
           var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http:///", "");
           $("#fileNames").append( "<li>" + filename + "</li>");
       });
       $("#fileNames").append('</ul>');
     }     
  });
```

*Basic logic referred from this SO question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480550/how-to-load-all-the-images-from-one-of-my-folder-into-my-web-page-using-jquery)*

Happy Coding :)

Comment: @NithinViswanathan:yes , did you try this logic ?

Comment: ( '<li>'+filename+<'/li'>); should be ( '<li>'+filename+'</li>');

Comment: Yeah that was a typo.

Comment: It's not working

Comment: I am getting syntax error ' [ '

Comment: @ZainShabir: it was untested code, they could be some compile-time errors due to typo mistake. why don't you create a working copy on stackblitz  and share here

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that it will work or not but you can try this

Give the name of image 1,2,3,4.....

and than show image using for loop like.

```
var imageFolder = '../../Images/Avatar/';

var imgsrc="";

for(var i=1; i <= totalImage; i++){
 imgsrc= imageFolder +i;

}
```

Comment: The images name will be different.. not be 1 2 3 like..