# Load background.image sequence from folder with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

i'm tring to make a javascript source that load all images in a folder as backgroundImage of my div

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url(/web/images/001.png)');
    });
</script>
```

How i can load all images (.png) in my folder (web/images) as background-image of a div?

Thanks for support,
M.

Comment: Is there any pattern in the files you want to load? is it sequential? eg.: 001.png, 002.png, 003.png? Do you want to use all images at the same time or do you want to have an interval between them?

Comment: If you add / (slash) at the begening of path, browser will search file in example.com/web/images/001.png

Comment: So your background will change from one image to another. am i right?

Comment: @nanndoj yes is a sequence

Comment: yes @shridhar correct

Comment: no @nanndoj no interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the background using a interval you should try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Function to add leading zeroes
    function pad(num, size) {
        var s = num + "";
        while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
        return s;
    }

    // Variable to store the current image index
    var currentIdx = 1; 
    var max = 200; // Qtd of images in the folder

    setInterval(function() {
        // Reset the index when overflow
        if(currentIdx > max) currentIdx = 1;
        // Change the background
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url(/web/images/' + pad(currentIdx,4) + '.png)');
        currentIdx ++;
    }, 5000); // 5000ms == 5 seconds
});
```

Here is a [Working Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/t4a13kk6/1/)

Comment: Hi, i've problem with your source, my images are from 0001.png to 0200.png, how i can make your script work?

Thanks.

Comment: Just change the pad number to 4 `pad(currentIdx,4)`, and set the `max` variable to 200

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imgno=1;
    for(var imgno=1;imgno<50;imgno++){
       $('div').css({'width':'200px','height':'200px','background-image': 'url(/web/images/'+imgno+'.png)'});
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/18480589/4599982 and you can use jquery setTimeout([settimeout](http://www.sitepoint.com/settimeout-example/) ) funcion for change of background after particular time.