# Dynamic HTML list multiple of x number of images with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, math, dynamic

I need to create a dynamic HTML list with images ordered in groups of three. Number of images is variable and they need to be multiple of 3 and the initial number of images

For example, I have this html list (in this case with eight images at first)

```
<ul>
        <li>
            <div class="sl3-big-image-div">
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/womanNew1.jpg"><div class="sl-price2 productPrice_7">9,99€</div></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/womanNew2.jpg"><div class="sl-price3 productPrice_8">9,99€</div></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/womanNew3.jpg"><div class="sl-price1 productPrice_1">9,99€</div></a>
            </div>
        </li><li>

            <div class="sl3-big-image-div">
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/womanNew4.jpg"><div class="sl-price2 productPrice_2">9,99€</div></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/womanNew5.jpg"><div class="sl-price3 productPrice_3">9,99€</div></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/womanNew6.jpg"><div class="sl-price1 productPrice_4">9,99€</div></a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="sl3-big-image-div">
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/womanNew7.jpg"><div class="sl-price2 productPrice_5">9,99€</div></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/womanNew8.jpg"><div class="sl-price3 productPrice_6">9,99€</div></a>

            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

and I want this result:

```
<li>
            <div class="sl3-big-image-div">
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/womanNew1.jpg"><div class="sl-price2 productPrice_7">9,99€</div></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/womanNew2.jpg"><div class="sl-price3 productPrice_8">9,99€</div></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/womanNew3.jpg"><div class="sl-price1 productPrice_1">9,99€</div></a>
            </div>
        </li><li>

            <div class="sl3-big-image-div">
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/womanNew4.jpg"><div class="sl-price2 productPrice_2">9,99€</div></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/womanNew5.jpg"><div class="sl-price3 productPrice_3">9,99€</div></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/womanNew6.jpg"><div class="sl-price1 productPrice_4">9,99€</div></a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="sl3-big-image-div">
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/womanNew7.jpg"><div class="sl-price2 productPrice_5">9,99€</div></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/womanNew8.jpg"><div class="sl-price3 productPrice_6">9,99€</div></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/womanNew1.jpg"><div class="sl-price3 productPrice_6">9,99€</div></a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="sl3-big-image-div">
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/manNew2.jpg"><div class="sl-price2 productPrice_8">9,99€</div></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/manNew3.jpg"><div class="sl-price3 productPrice_1">9,99€</div></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/manNew4.jpg"><div class="sl-price1 productPrice_2">9,99€</div></a>

            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="sl3-big-image-div">
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/manNew5.jpg"><div class="sl-price2 productPrice_3">9,99€</div></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/manNew6.jpg"><div class="sl-price3 productPrice_4">9,99€</div></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/manNew7.jpg"><div class="sl-price1 productPrice_5">9,99€</div></a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="sl3-big-image-div">
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/manNew8.jpg"><div class="sl-price2 productPrice_6">9,99€</div></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/manNew1.jpg"><div class="sl-price3 productPrice_7">9,99€</div></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/manNew2.jpg"><div class="sl-price1 productPrice_8">9,99€</div></a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="sl3-big-image-div">
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/manNew3.jpg"><div class="sl-price2 productPrice_1">9,99€</div></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/manNew4.jpg"><div class="sl-price3 productPrice_2">9,99€</div></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/manNew5.jpg"><div class="sl-price1 productPrice_3">9,99€</div></a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="sl3-big-image-div">
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/manNew6.jpg"><div class="sl-price2 productPrice_4">9,99€</div></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/manNew7.jpg"><div class="sl-price3 productPrice_5">9,99€</div></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="sl4-big-image" src="images/manNew8.jpg"><div class="sl-price1 productPrice_6">9,99€</div></a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

As you can see now every li element has three images. Number of images are a multiple of 8 and 3(so there are 24 images ordered in group of three images now).

any ideas please?

Comment: "so there are 24 images ordered in group of three images now", But there are only 14 images and the third `li` has 2 images.

Comment: That is an example of the 'initial' html. There are 8 images and the third li has 2 images.  I want to change that html dinamically with js.

Comment: "As you can see now every li element has three images", even in your last example (what you want to be the result) the third `li` has 2 images.

Comment: It was a mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so what you want is no matter how much images are there initially, you want 8 `<li>` tags and 3 `<img>` within each `<li>` tag. Right?

Comment: Initial number of images (x) is important because final number of images need to be multiple of 3 and x.

Comment: So, we start with 8 images. You need JS to dynamically change them to 24 because 24 is a  multiple of 3 and 8?

Comment: If you want to fix the HTML because when it is downloaded from the server it isn't valid, why don't you just stop the server sending bad data?

Comment: yes, but number of images is variable. The code is just an example.

Comment: @AbelAbad Ok, I'll try to find a solution and post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple pieces to this. First would be pulling in the images from the desired directory. You'll need to use AJAX to accomplish this. After looking at [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480550/how-to-load-all-the-images-from-one-of-my-folder-into-my-web-page-using-jquery) you'd probably want to start with:

```
var dir = "imageDirectory/";
var fileextension = ".jpg";
$.ajax({
    url: dir,
    success: function (data) {
        var foundFiles = $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")");
        if (foundFiles && foundFiles.length) {
            var fileArr = new Array();
            foundFiles.each(function() {
               var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http:///", "");
               var imgEl = "<img src=" + dir + filename + " />";
               fileArr.push(imgEl);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

From there you'll just need to loop through the array and build the html, inserting the `div` and `li` tags every 3:

```
var htmlArr = new Array();
htmlArr.push("<ul>");
for (var z = 0; z < fileArr.length; z++) {
    if (z == 0) {
        htmlArr.push("<li>");
        htmlArr.push("<div>");        
    }
    if (z !==0 && z % 3 === 0) {
        htmlArr.push("</div>");
        htmlArr.push("</li>");
        htmlArr.push("<li>");
        htmlArr.push("<div>");
    }
    htmlArr.push(fileArr[z]);
    if (z == fileArr.length-1) {
        htmlArr.push("</div>");
        htmlArr.push("</li>");
    }
}
htmlArr.push("</ul>");
var htmlOut = htmlArr.join("");
$("body").append(htmlOut);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uxgqy9y8/1/