# javascript : open files with the value of select

Tags: javascript, jquery, file

I have load all files from one of my folder into my web page with this question : [How to load all the images from one of my folder into my web page, using Jquery/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480550/how-to-load-all-the-images-from-one-of-my-folder-into-my-web-page-using-jquery) 
I use this explanation to make a select of my files like this :

```
<select>
<option value="path/to/file1">option1</option>
<option value="path/to/file2">option2</option>
...
</select>
```

How can I open my files with this select?

Comment: What kind of files?  Images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select onchange="open_my_file()" id="ajax_fele">
  <option value="path/to/file1">option1</option>
  <option value="path/to/file2">option2</option>
  ...
</select>

<script>
  function open_my_file(){
  var file_url = $("#ajax_fele").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: file_url,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //data have file content.
            }, error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //error 
            }
        });
  }
</script>
```

Just make is simple with ajax call.