# search for image in given folder using JavaScript and ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need to make small app using html and JavaScript to search for image in given folder.

for example i have folder called `/images` with `f1.jpg, f2.gif, f3.png` images and html webpage with search input. when i search for `f1` it should print the `f1.jpg` image with `<img>` tag bellow the search input.

How i can do that with html and javascript or ajax without print all images?

Html example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search images</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
var folder = "images/";

$.ajax({
    url : folder,
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
            if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
                $("body").append( "<img src='"+ folder + val +"'>" );
            } 
        });
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<label>Search for image:</label>
<br />
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="">
<button type="submit">Search</button>
<br />
<!-- Image result should appear here -->
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32940532/383904

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan stackoverflow.com/a/32940532/383904 this search and print all images and my question is different!

Comment: I see no issue in your code, actually there's no JS code in your question, so please, be so kind, try something from the suggested link, patch some click handler, query the folder, get the image, write some code, than come back with a question with some code that has some real issue.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan question edited.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that without php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need `ajax` for this. you can just look if image is loaded or not using `onload` event of `Image` as shown below

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = path_to_image;

img.onerror = function() {
  // any logic in case of error
};

img.onload = function() {
  document.body.appendChild(img);
};
```

You can have a look at this example
https://plnkr.co/edit/RWH73qp0jmOZeymvV6Aq?p=preview

**Note:** you can create your image url using `predefined_path_to_folder + search_input_value` and use it as value for `img.src`

Comment: Yes, that could work if OP wants to play guess game with it's users: *enter an image name and hope we'll find it :)* Kidding. Not. But would be useful in any case to show a list of available images... just thinking loud...

Comment: user don't really need to guess. `onload` of page we should run a background script to find all available images using above code (assuming file name follows pattern like f1.png, f2.png, f3.png etc.) and then create a autocomplete for end user with that list.