# How to load all the images from one Directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i tried to display all images in one directory using following `jquery`. But it is not working. My folder structure is just a images folder and `js` folder.
I just followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480550/how-to-load-all-the-images-from-one-of-my-folder-into-my-web-page-using-jquery) question also, but couldnt achive the target.

[image]

```js
< script >
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var folder = "images/";
    $.ajax({
      url: folder,
      success: function(data) {
        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function(i, val) {
          if (val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/)) {
            $("body").append("<img src='" + folder + val + "'>");
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }); < /script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Satpal here i used Ajax request. and there are  many acceptance of previous question i have link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480550/how-to-load-all-the-images-from-one-of-my-folder-into-my-web-page-using-jquery)

Comment: Then share the returned HTML from the AJAX request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to create a server page which will provide you list of names from that directory. you need to call that page (instead of folder name) from your $.ajax function.

Second, loop over that list of image names (paths) and create image elements. You are doing the similar stuff.

Answer (score -1):

Javascript does not have access to file system. Alternatively you can send an ajax request to your server-scide script to list the file names and return the names back to your script OR you can use [server side javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Server-side_JavaScript)