# Dynamically embed videos in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to be able to dynamically embed videos from a source into an html page. For example, if I wanted to add a new video to my page I would simply just have to place it in a folder and have it automatically be embedded in my html page. I would like (if possible) to do this using JavaScript and jQuery. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Would this only be on your end or should the video get saved to your server?

Comment: So eventually the idea is to access the videos from a database and have them upload to an internal resource here at the company I intern for. Ideally my boss would like to place the videos on the database and have them upload automatically to our "Help" page on our site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be done like this:

1. Scan the folder
2. Look for the correct extension
3. Append videos to the page

   ```
   var folder = "videos/";

   $.ajax({
       url : folder,
           success: function (data) {
               $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
               if( val.match(/\.(mp4)$/) ) { 
                   $("body").append( "
                       <video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
                           <source src='"+ folder + val +"' type="video/mp4">
                       </video>
                   " );
               } 
           });
       }
   });
   ```

*Idea taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/32940532/7117409*

Comment: Thank you! Looks like that definitely set me on the right track. Now my console is throwing XMLHttpRequest error. "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https." Probably because I'm testing on a separate test .html file I created? I'll look into it more.

Comment: Because you're on local. It has to be on a web server, even localhost.

Comment: That's what I was assuming. Thank you!