# How to display all images of a directory using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How to display all images of a directory using jquery ? There is no common pattern for image name.

Comment: This can't be done using jQuery. You need server code to list the contents of a directory, it can't be done by the client itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load all the images from one of my folder into my web page, using Jquery/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480550/how-to-load-all-the-images-from-one-of-my-folder-into-my-web-page-using-jquery)