# Ajax call throws 404 when loading images from folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to load images from folder via jquery and ajax and I'm using the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480550/how-to-load-all-the-images-from-one-of-my-folder-into-my-web-page-using-jquery). However, this throws a 404 error - even though the directory definitely exists, and I even can access the files in it.

Here's the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var folder = "images/";

$.ajax({
    url: folder,
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
            if (val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/)) {
                $('#galerie').append('<a class="image_anchor" data-fancybox="gallery" href="resources/img/header_bg.jpg"><img src="' + folder + val + '" /></a>')
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is mentioned in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480550/how-to-load-all-the-images-from-one-of-my-folder-into-my-web-page-using-jquery) you looked at

```
//This will retrieve the contents of the folder if the folder is configured as 'browsable'
```

Put a .htaccess file in the directory where your images are located. The content of the .htaccess file should look like:

```
Options +Indexes
```

More info: https://support.tigertech.net/directory-index

Please keep in mind you need to run the page on a webserver since you are using .htaccess (no PHP needed)

Answer (score 1):

It was caused by

1. not having .htaccess in the directory
2. using the WebStorm instead of xampp (I do not know why, but it just does not work on WebStorm server)