# Ajax jquery load local mac folder of images: Match undefined error

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tried applying [below code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480550/how-to-load-all-the-images-from-one-of-my-folder-into-my-web-page-using-jquery) after opening Chrome in terminal with allow-file-access-from-files (did latter because without was hitting an origin 'null' CORS security prob) but still no luck uploading local mac folder of images (.jpg) to a website (below quoted error message).

Any help with where I'm going wrong would be greatly appreciated. I'm very new to this - the webpage is just my .txt file.

i_stack

```
    var folder = "imgFolder/";

$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
    url : folder,
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
         if(val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/)) {
                $("body").append( "<img src="+ folder + val +">" );
            }  
        });
    }
});
```

> Cannot read property 'match' of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that not all your `<a>` elements have `href` attributes. For those elements, `val` will be `undefined`.

You can easily refine your selector to

```js
$(data).find('a[href]').attr(...)
```

This way, you're guaranteed to only be looking at `<a>` elements with an `href` attribute.

Comment: Thanks Phil for the response. Changing that line to $(data).find('a[href]').attr("href", function (i, val) { gets rid of the match undefined error, which is nice. But alas, the images still do not appear. i_stack

Comment: Try logging the data returned, ie `console.log(data)`. Is it HTML? Does it have any `<a>` elements?

Comment: This is the excerpt containing the only three, apologies - I guess being new I am overlooking something very obvious:

<div id="listingParsingErrorBox">Oh, no! This server is sending data Google Chrome can't understand. Please <a href="http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry">report a bug</a>, and include the <a href="LOCATION">raw listing</a>.</div>

<h1 id="header">Index of LOCATION</h1>

<div id="parentDirLinkBox" style="display:none">
  <a id="parentDirLink" class="icon up">
    <span id="parentDirText">[parent directory]</span>
  </a>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in kind of a solution, the initially referenced code worked after I downloaded MAMP and configured it to bypass the CORS prob.

I can't speak at all to the appropriateness (efficiency, security etc.) of this method but I have casually come across cautions relating to CORS bypass.

Thanks again Phil for humouring me. It seems I was barking up the wrong tree initially.

i_stack