# How do I fetch all images in a folder with AJAX using pure JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get all the images in a folder with an AJAX request (for use in an image slider). I've found [this jQuery solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480550/how-to-load-all-the-images-from-one-of-my-folder-into-my-web-page-using-jquery/18480589) which works perfectly fine, except that it uses jQuery. What would a pure JS equivalent look like? (i.e. XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: the server would have to return a response with the directory listing.

Comment: Which parts exactly are you having problems with converting? Do you understand the jQuery example?

Comment: @FelixKling I think I do at least. :) The line where it looks for anchors with the href attribute I find a bit weird though... The .find could be where I get stuck here. The equivalent would be a querySelectorAll pretty much right?

Comment: @Rainman http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: Great site @Amy , hanging out there right now  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [@FZs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8376184/fzs) help this is what I ended up with. Thank you!

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "/img", true);
xhr.responseType = 'document';
xhr.onload = () => {
  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    var elements = xhr.response.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (x of elements) {
      if ( x.href.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
          let img = document.createElement("img");
          img.src = x.href;
          document.body.appendChild(img);
      } 
    };
  } 
  else {
    alert('Request failed. Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
  }
}
xhr.send()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without jQuery! Maybe with more code, but this should work (adapted from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32940532/8376184))):

```
    var folder = "images/";
    var ajax=new XMLHttpRequest()
    ajax.open("GET",folder,true)
    ajax.onload=function () {
        var elements=(new DOMParser()).parseFromString(ajax.responseText,"text/html").getElementsByTagname("A")
        for(x of elements){
            if(request.status[0]==2 && x.href.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/)) { 
                let img=document.createElement("IMG")
                img.src=folder+x.href
                document.body.appendChild(img);
            } 
        };
    }
    ajax.send()
```

Or, you can force `XMLHttpRequest` to parse document (idea from [@Rainman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11233939/rainman)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55268506/how-do-i-fetch-all-images-in-a-folder-with-ajax-using-pure-js/55268776?noredirect=1#comment97271281_55268776)):

```
ajax.responseType = "document"
```

So the code becomes to the following:

```
    var folder = "images/";
    var ajax=new XMLHttpRequest()
    ajax.open("GET",folder,true)
    ajax.onload=function () {
        ajax.responseType="document"
        var elements=ajax.responseText.getElementsByTagname("A")
        for(x of elements){
            if(request.status[0]==2 && x.href.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/)) { 
                let img=document.createElement("IMG")
                img.src=folder+x.href
                document.body.appendChild(img);
            } 
        };
    }
    ajax.send()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the hasty and pretty looking response :) ajax.responseXML at line 5 returns null for me though?

Comment: From [MDN XHR.responseXML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Properties): *Returns a Document containing the response to the request, or null if the request was unsuccessful, has not yet been sent, or cannot be parsed as XML or HTML.* **So, what's the content available on the requested URL?**

Comment: Hm yes... It's a bunch of jpg images

Comment: @Rainman Make a file to the folder `index.php`/`asp`/`html`/whatever you use, which contains the `<a>` links, **OR** use a different location for the request and replace folder on the 9th line with the image folder name! Additionally, I edited my post to handle server errors

Comment: Doesn't seem to be an issue with the path or location since I get the html anchors with the correct hrefs printed out if i console log only "ajax.response".

Comment: @Rainman OK... it's a strange issue, but you can use `.response` instead of `.responseXML`. Do you get a string or a Document object when logging `ajax.response`?

Comment: .response returns a string, so I wound have to do things differently after that

Comment: @Rainman Is your string formatted as a valid HTML, or it only contains `<a>` elements?

Comment: It contains an entire valid HTML document as a string that includes the anchors in the body.

Comment: @Rainman I edited my answer again, now using [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to handle the situation

Comment: I think I just solved it! By adding ajax.responseType = 'document'; before the .onload

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and patiance @FZs!